# Python Mock Unittest Asserting Mysql Resultsets

Tags: python, mysql, unit-testing, mocking

I am having a really hard time wrapping my head around using Mock to do non-trivial unit tests in Python. I do not want to use the production databases for my test suits and want to create a testing-only database.

Let's say I want to create a mock database with these 3 tables containing this data:

```
FRUIT
id      Name
1       Apple
2       Pear
3       Orange

 COLOR
 id     Name
 1      Red
 2      Yellow
 3      Orange

 FRUIT_COLOR
 id     fruit_id    color_id
 1      1            1
 2      1            2
 3      2            2
 4      3            3
```

Now let's say I have the following function:

```
def assess_fruit(self):
    query = """
        SELECT 
        f.name AS FRUIT,
        c.name AS COLOR
        FROM fruit_color AS fc
        JOIN fruit AS f ON f.id = fc.fruit_id
        JOIN color AS c ON c.id = fc.color_id
        WHERE color.name = 'Red';
     """
    cursor.execute(self._query)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    return results
```

How do I got about using Mock to make this database and test that the results should be something like this list of tuples?

```
 [(Apple, Red), (Apple, Yellow)]
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Python unit test `TestCase` class has 2 methods `setUp` and `tearDown` which are called when your test cases starts and ends. You can add code to `CREATE` the tables and `INSERT` data into the tables in these 2 methods. See example below:

```
from unittest import TestCase


class TestMyData(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        query = """
        CREATE TABLE FRUIT (
            id INT,
            Name VARCHAR(255)
        );
        INSERT INTO FRUIT (id, Name)
        VALUES (1, 'Apple'),
               (2, 'Pear'),
               (3, 'Orange');
        """
        cursor.execute(query)

        # Add CREATE & INSERT table statements for COLOR and FRUIT_COLOR tables

    def assess_fruit(self):
        query = """
            SELECT
            f.name AS FRUIT,
            c.name AS COLOR
            FROM fruit_color AS fc
            JOIN fruit AS f ON f.id = fc.fruit_id
            JOIN color AS c ON c.id = fc.color_id
            WHERE color.name = 'Red';
         """
        cursor.execute(query)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        return results

    def tearDown(self):
        query = """
        DROP TABLE FRUIT;
        DROP TABLE COLOR;
        DROP TABLE FRUIT_COLOR;
        """
        cursor.execute(query)
```

If you would like to learn how to actually mock your calls to the database then you can take a look at [this blog post](http://kirankoduru.github.io/python/mocking-with-python.html) I wrote not too long ago.

Comment: Is the data that's being written this way saved to disk? Is there a way to use the Mock library (or any other method) to keep the database entirely in memory between the setUp and tearDown functions?

Comment: Yes. This will be written to your mock database which claimed to create in your question.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that's good to know. I'm having a hard time knowing how to ask the right questions. I currently don't have a test db on hard disk, I need to create _something_. If there is a way to do it all in memory, that will be optimal. If not, the answer you posted is an excellent starting place. Thank you.